# Can I add subscriptions to my apple app later?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an app store app in beta testing and would like to publish it now and add subscriptions later which will unlock some limitations.

Can I publish my app as a totally free right now and add in-app purchase subscriptions later?

Comment: Yes. You can add in app purchases with an update, but make sure that your first version doesn't make any mention of the features that aren't available.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for the answer. I will remove anything related to “paid features”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only can you, you should. The procedure for adding an in app purchase is much easier if the app already exists on the store.